# drop down show only when value comes from database otherwise hide

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am using jquery-ajax to show multiple depandant  drop down . all things going right but i have  an issue which is that when there is no value aginst a selected drop down , then the child drop down must hide it self ..  but in my code it show itself empty . i want that  child drop down list hide ..kindly help me in this regard ..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#parent_state").change(function() {

$.get('loadsubcat.php?parent_state=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
$("#city").html(data);


 });
 });

 });
 /script>

 <?php 
$con=mysql_connect( 'localhost' , '' , ''); 
if($con){
    mysql_select_db('test' , $con);
    //echo "database selected";
}
    ?>
    <form method="post">
        <?php
            $sql= "SELECT * FROM state";
            $rs= mysql_query($sql);

            if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0){
                ?>  
                <select name="parent_state" id="parent_state">
                <option value""></option>
                <?php
                while($nrow=mysql_fetch_array($rs)){

       echo "<option value=".$nrow['state_id']. ">".$nrow['state_name']. "</option>";           

        }
?> </select>
            <?php
        }

        ?>


   <select name="city" id="city">
    <option value=""></option>
 </select>



</form>
```

this is loadsubcat.php

```
  $parent_state = $_GET['parent_state'];

 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM city WHERE state_id = {$parent_state}");
 if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
 echo "<option value=".$row['city_id']. ">".$row['city_name']. "</option>";
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you move the other drop-down(one with the name="city"), inside the if condition? With that, if the parent drop-down doesn't exist, neither will the child.

Something like this -

```
...
if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0){
    ?>  
    <select name="parent_state" id="parent_state">
        <option value""></option>
        <?php
            while($nrow=mysql_fetch_array($rs)){

            echo "<option value=".$nrow['state_id']. ">".$nrow['state_name']. "</option>";           

            }
        ?>
    </select>
        //I've added the child select here.
    <select name="city" id="city">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
<?php
}
?>
...
```

Comment: i had already try this .. but it is not working for me .. if u have any other solution then  kindly help me ..

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your script to this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#parent_state").change(function() {
        $("#city").load('loadsubcat.php?parent_state=' + $(this).val());
      });
 });
 </script>
```

I've had issues with $.get before as well, trying to pass data that way. If you insist on using $.get you should put the data in json format and pass is to the function as a parameter. see the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

But in this case i think .load is the appropriate answer

Another thing to be aware of is that having spaces in your parameters will cause an issue. A safe way of dealing with this is to encode the parameters ie..

```
$("#parent_state").change(function() {
        params = encodeURI($(this).val());
        $("#city").load('loadsubcat.php?parent_state=' + params);
      });
```

Comment: you're going to need to do some debugging , hows it not working?